# Getting the literal value of a parameter to a sweet.js macro

Tags: sweet.js

I've got a macro defined and I'm trying to test one of the values passed as a parameter to determine how to emit code.  However, I keep getting errors thrown when I try to use the value.  Here is a simple test that illustrates the problem:

```
let Test = macro {
    case {
        _ ($arg1,$arg2,$arg3)
    } => {
        if ($arg1 ==1) {
            return #{ 
                f($arg1,$arg2,$arg3)
            }
        } else {
            return #{
                g($arg1,$arg2,$arg3)
            }
        }
    }
}

Test(1,2,3)
```

The error I get is:

```
ReferenceError: $arg1 is not defined
```

I've taken various stabs by calling makeIdent, syntaxUnwrap, etc. without any luck.  How can I test the value passed?

Update: After playing around with some things I discovered that I can use this construct to get the value:

```
#{$arg1}[0].token.value
```

But then I found [this page](https://github.com/mozilla/sweet.js/issues/178) which suggested that at one point `token.value.raw` was used instead of `token.value`, which further suggests that since I'm not going through the official documented API I may be accessing undocumented internals which are subject to change.